# Multiple Model Access in .NET Editor Templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-editor-templates

I am trying to create a more "advanced" editor template for my MVC web application, but I am having a little bit of difficulty. Before I explain, let me show my source code.

Here is the code in my view (using the template):

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Height, "UnitTemplate", new { unitModel = Model.HeightUnit, unitType = Units.Distance })
```

Here is the template:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@using MyProject.Models;

@{
    var unitModel = this.ViewData["unitModel"];
    var unitType = this.ViewData["unitType"] as SelectList;
}

<div class="data-group">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model)
    </div>
    <div class="option1">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model)
    </div>
    <div class="units">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => unitModel, unitType, new { @class = "unit" })</div>
    <div class="validation">
        <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have some value (in this case, Height) and I also have a unit type associated with that value (HeightUnit). I want to be able to GENERICALLY pass in the unit value associated with the model (since I am using this template in quite a number of places) as well as well as the type of unit (since this can also change). Ultimately, the goal is to allow the user to convert quickly between values.

Fortunately, everything works up to this point (conversion, population, etc), except that, when I save the results, the unitModel does NOT save to the database. Does anybody have suggestions for what I can do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use an editor template for the entire model in this case as this template depends on multiple properties of the main view model (`Height` and `HeightUnit`):

```
@Html.EditorForModel("UnitTemplate")
```

and then in the `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/UnitTemplate.cshtml` editor template:

```
@using MyProject.Models;
@model MyViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<div class="data-group">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Height)
    </div>
    <div class="option1">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Height)
    </div>
    <div class="units">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            model => model.HeightUnit, 
            Units.Distance, 
            new { @class = "unit" }
        )
    </div>
    <div class="validation">
        <div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Height)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did think of that, but, the problem here is, the name of the unit variables differ, as do the unit types. I plan on using this template throughout my site with more than just one or two values.

Comment: @JasCav, if the variable your are binding your dropdownlist to differs you will need to re-adapt the view models that your POST action receives in order to properly bind the selected value. Look at name attribute that has been generated in the HTML source and you should use this same name in the POST action to fetch the value.

Comment: Okay, that makes some sense. I did look at the name and saw that everything is named "[modelName].unitType" - so Height.unitType in this example. I'm not sure I understand how to bind this in the controller. If you could provide an example, it would be much appreciated. +1 in the meantime.

Comment: @JasCav, there are different possibilities. The first is to design a view model which contains a string property named `UnitType` and then design another class which has a property called `Height` and which is of the first model type. Then the model binder will automatically do the binding. Another possibility is to fetch it from the request: `var unitType = Request["Height.unitType"];`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I ran into another issue where the DropDownList doesn't populate even if I manage to get the correct results back to the database. (Presumably because it doesn't link up properly in the beginning.) I might have to reconsider my solution (or just hand code everything - templates would be very nice, though).